# JOIN ... WHERE vs. CASE WHEN for optimizing filters?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a performance difference between doing a self-join vs. case expression when filtering a large table? For example, I have a list of names and professions, and I want to create a column that is only populated if a person is a doctor.

I did this in two ways:

1. CASE WHEN

```
select name
, case 
    when profession = 'doctor' 
      then profession 
    else null 
  end as is_doctor
from professions
```

2. LEFT JOIN ... WHERE

```
select name
, is_doctor
from professions
  left join (
    select name
    , profession 
    from professions 
    where profession = 'doctor'
  ) d on professions.name = d.name
```

I know that WHERE tends to be less costly than CASE WHEN, but the LEFT JOIN could make it slower. The first is more readable but I'm wondering if the second is more efficient.

Comment: why not test it yourself with data, but imho no

Comment: Only high end database engines will be able to figure out that the second query is equivalent to the first one (that is much cheaper). Typical databases (SQL Server, MySQL, Sybase, etc) won't be able to optimize the second one and they are gonna be much slower.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't actually need the derived table in the second example. `left join professions d on professions.name = d.name and d.name = 'doctor'` will achieve the same

Comment: You're not likely to get a straight answer about this because nobody knows for sure, especially without your data and your actual query.  “Query optimization is not rocket science.  When you flunk out of query optimization, we make you go build rockets.” - David Dewitt, 2010

Comment: Both queries have the boolean expression `profession = 'doctor'`, so one turns the boolean result in to a string using `CASE` (a scalar expression where all the necessary values have already been read), the other finds the name, looks the name up in an index then reads the profession. Unless you have a way for all that to happen for free, take a guess at how they're going to compare.

Comment: You’re the only person who can measure this for your data. Could you please share the results?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know from where you got the idea that `CASE` is slow. The first query, having no join, is bound to perform at least as good as the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name
, case 
    when profession = 'doctor' 
      then profession 
  end as is_doctor
from professions
```

...is likely easier to maintain.  So, in terms of developer time, it's way faster.

Assuming this is a trivial example of your actual, complicated SQL query -- and shaving off a few milliseconds here and there really does matter -- you'll want to use your complicated SQL against your large data set(s) to perform your own testing.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, the former case is nearly twice as  fast and reads less data than the latter when ran against my database. From what I could understand from the EXPLAIN, the join was too expensive as it had to repartition the table.